# How to search for files by tags?

Tags: nautilus, files, tagging, tracker

I can tag files with nautilus but haven't found a solution to find files by tags so far. Tracker-search-tool doesn't offer to search for tags, nor does Nautilus, nor any other application I'm aware of. Just upgraded to 11.04.

Comment: I was sure that there was a facility in tracker to search by tags but that may have been linked to nepomuk which I used to have with kubuntu

Answer (score 6):

It's called tracker-tag:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/tracker-tag.1.html

It's provided by the tracker-utils package, which is the command line version of the tracker facility.

```
-s -- lists all files associated with a tag
-a -- Add a tag to a file
```

**Example**

To add a tag:

```
tracker-tag -a TAG file
```

To search by tag:

```
tracker-tag -s TAG
Result: 1
  /home/sean/file
```

**Real world Examples from my system**

```
<sean@mymachine:~> tracker-tag -a TAG exten
<sean@mymachine:~> tracker-tag -a testing atreides master.ldif php_error.log TrainingUpdates.otl

<sean@mymachine:~> tracker-tag -s testing
Results: 5
  /home/sean/TrainingUpdates.otl
  /home/sean/atreides
  /home/sean/exten
  /home/sean/master.ldif
  /home/sean/php_error.log

<sean@mymachine:~> tracker-tag -a myTagExample TrainingUpdates.otl atreides exten master.ldif php_error.log 
<sean@mymachine:~> tracker-tag -s myTagExample
Results: 5
  /home/sean/TrainingUpdates.otl
  /home/sean/atreides
  /home/sean/exten
  /home/sean/master.ldif
  /home/sean/php_error.log

<sean@mymachine:~> tracker-tag -s TAG
Result: 1
  /home/sean/exten
```

Comment: That's not correct - in conjunction with the -t option it lists ALLO tags and All the files associated with them.

Comment: Hmmm ... Seems to work pretty well on my system.

Answer (score 2):

Nautilus in gnome-team ppa has a plugin for add-remove tags, bun nof for searching. When I asked for a new panel view to nautilus team (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=670163) got this answer.

```
- the interface that allows to add tracker tags from Nautilus is not part of
Nautilus, but it's an extension
- we will not add any additional side pane, since we intentionally trimmed them
down to Places and Tree for Nautilus 3.0
- I think the best way to do what you want is from Tracker itself; if the UI
utilities shipped with Tracker don't allow you to do this, you should file a
bug against Tracker for it
```

So I've made a nautilus-python extension just for this. Install python-nautilus and submitted to tracker https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=670643

```
sudo apt-get install python nautilus
```

Then copy next code and save under .local/share/nautilus-python/extensions/[filename].py

```
#natxooy@gmail.com
#nautilus etiketa bilatzaile
#v 0.1

from gi.repository import Nautilus, GObject
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import Pixbuf
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT,call
from os import path,environ
from sys import platform
from urllib import unquote
from mimetypes import guess_type
import locale

class TagsManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d={}
        self.dtag={}
        cmd='tracker-tag -t'
        p=Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,close_fds=True)
        output = p.stdout.read()
        l=output.split('\n')
        while('' in l): l.remove('')
        if len(l)>3:
            for i in range(2,len(l),3):
                if i+2<len(l):self.d[l[i].strip()]=int(l[i+2][:l[i+2].find('f')])
            original_list=[i for i in self.d.keys()]
        #lk.sort()
        decorated = [(s.lower(), s) for s in original_list]
        decorated.sort()
        lk = [s[1] for s in decorated]
        print lk
        for tag in lk:
            if self.d[tag]<>0:
                cmd='tracker-tag -t -s'
                p=Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,close_fds=True)
                output = p.stdout.read()
                l=output.split('\n')
                ll= [unquote(i.strip()).decode('utf-8') for i in l]
                ini=ll.index(tag)
                lkini=lk.index(unicode(tag))
                if tag==lk[-1]:
                    resp=ll[ini+1:]
                    while('' in resp): resp.remove('')
                else:
                    fin=ll.index(lk[lkini+1])
                    resp=[ll[i] for i in range(ini+1,fin)]
                self.dtag[tag]=resp

class Ventana:
    def clic(self, widget, event, data=None):
        l=[]
        lista_nueva=[]
        for i in self.todas.get_selection().get_selected_rows()[1]:
            t= self.todas.get_model().get_value(self.todas.get_model().get_iter(i), 0)
            l.append(t)
        if len(l)==1:
            lista_nueva=[i for i in self.tm.dtag[l[0]]]
        elif len(l)>1:
            lista_nueva=[i for i in self.tm.dtag[l[0]]]
            for i in l[1:]:
                ll=[]
                for f in self.tm.dtag[i]:
                    if f in lista_nueva: ll.append(f)
                lista_nueva=[f for f in ll]
        else:lista_nueva=[]
        self.files.get_model().clear()
        lista=[f.encode('utf-8')[7:] for f in lista_nueva]
        lf=[i for i in lista if path.isfile(i)]
        ld=[i for i in lista if not path.isfile(i)]
        lista_nueva=ld+lf
        for f in lista_nueva:
            mime_type= guess_type(path.basename(f))
            if mime_type[0]<>None:
                icon= 'gnome-mime-'+mime_type[0].replace('/','-')
            else:
                print f.encode('utf-8'),path.isfile(f)
                if path.isfile(f):icon='gtk-file'
                else:icon='folder'
            pixbuf = gtk.IconTheme.get_default().load_icon(icon, 48, 0)
            self.files.get_model().append([pixbuf,path.basename(f),f])
        return False

    def open_file(self, iconview, ipath):
        model = iconview.get_model()
        iter = model.get_iter(ipath)
        filename = model.get_value(iter, 2)
        if platform == 'linux2':
            call(["xdg-open", filename])
        return

    def __init__(self):
        self.tm=TagsManager()
        self.paned = gtk.HPaned()

        self.existentags = gtk.ListStore(str)
        tags=[i for i in self.tm.d.keys()]
        tags.sort()
        for t in tags:
            self.existentags.append([t])
        self.todas = gtk.TreeView(self.existentags)
        self.todas.get_selection().set_mode(gtk.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE)
        cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.todas.connect("button_release_event", self.clic, None)
        column0=gtk.TreeViewColumn("Tags",cell, text=0)
        self.todas.append_column(column0) 
        scrolled_window = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolled_window.set_policy(gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC, gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)
        scrolled_window.add_with_viewport (self.todas)
        self.paned.add1(scrolled_window)

        self.listfiles = gtk.ListStore(Pixbuf,str,str)
        self.files = gtk.IconView.new()
        self.files.set_model(self.listfiles)
        self.files.set_pixbuf_column(0)
        self.files.set_text_column(1)
        self.files.connect('item-activated', self.open_file)
        scrolled_window2 = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolled_window2.set_policy(gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC, gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)
        scrolled_window2.add_with_viewport (self.files)
        self.paned.add2(scrolled_window2)
        self.paned.set_position(150)
        self.paned.show_all()

class PApplication(gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.dialog = gtk.Dialog ("Etiketa iragazkia", window, gtk.DialogFlags.MODAL,
                                      (gtk.STOCK_CLOSE, gtk.ResponseType.CLOSE,))
        self.dialog.set_icon_name (gtk.STOCK_EDIT)
        self.dialog.set_size_request(600, 400)

        TS=Ventana()
        self.dialog.vbox.pack_start (TS.paned,expand=True, fill=True, padding=0)

class Pr(GObject.GObject, Nautilus.MenuProvider):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def ojo(self,menu,window):
        d=PApplication(window)
        r=d.dialog.run()
        d.dialog.destroy()
        return

    def get_background_items(self, window, files):
        return self.menuItem(window)

    def get_file_items(self, window, files):
        return self.menuItem(window)

    def menuItem(self, window):
        self.window=window
        P = Nautilus.MenuItem(
            name="Etiketa iragazkia::Etiketa iragazkia",
            label="Etiketa iragazkia",
            tip="Etiketa iragazkia"
        )
        P.connect('activate', self.ojo, window)
        return [P]
```

And finally restart nautilus

```
nautilus -q
```

When you right-clic any file or in the background a new menu item 'Etiketa iragazkia' (tag filter in basque).

Answer (score 2):

Search for tags from the command line with tracker-tag. The above mentioned search syntax does not work on my system (12.04). The "-s" option is only available with "--list":

```
tracker-tag --list -s [tag]
```

This is rather a comment on the first answer but I still lack some reps to be able to comment :-(