# tracker-tag returns "Files aren't indexed"

Tags: tracker, tagging

I'm trying to use `tracker-tag` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/42364/239377).
However, whenever I try to add a tag to a file using `tracker-tag -a TAGNAME FILE`, it returns

> Files do not exist or aren't indexed

Obviously, the file exists, but I'm not too sure of the "aren't indexed" part. Zeitgeist seems to be active.

Don't know if it could be of help, but this is the output of `tracker-control`

```
Found 334 PIDs…
Found process ID 22935 for 'tracker-store'

Store:
14 mar 2015, 10:49:56:  ✓     Store                 - Idle 

Miners:
14 mar 2015, 10:49:56:  ✗     Applications          - Not running or is a disabled plugin
14 mar 2015, 10:49:56:  ✗     File System           - Not running or is a disabled plugin
```